# ¿Qué significan tres puntos (...) en java y cómo se usan?

Tags: java

He visto un método que está escrito de la siguiente forma.

```
public void metodox(int  ... args) {

}
```

Probé pasarle parámetros y acepta una cantidad **N** de parámetros.

```
metodox(1,2,3,4);
metodox(1,2);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Significa varargs y sirve para pasar 0 o más parámetros del mismo tipo. Por ejemplo, el método que indicas:

```
public void metodoX(int ... args) {
}
```

Soporta que puedas pasar 0, 1 o más argumentos de tipo `int` solamente.

Se puede usar varargs solo como el último tipo de parámetro a usar en un método. Por ejemplo:

```
public void metodoX(String mensaje, int ... args) { }
```

Significa que el primer argumento debe ser un `String` y los demás (0, 1 o más) son de tipo `int`.

En caso que coloques una variable tipo varargs, no puede ir ninguna definición de variable luego de esto. Ejemplo:

```
//error de compilación
public void metodoX(int ... args, String s) { }
```

Java interpreta los parámetros varargs como un arreglo. Por ejemplo, una implementación para el método sería:

```
public void metodoX(int ... args) {
    for (int numero : args {
        System.out.print(numero + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Por lo cual, también admite que en lugar de enviar múltiples argumentos, puedas enviar un arreglo en su lugar. Ejemplo:

```
metodoX(1, 2, 3);
metodoX(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Salida:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

**Importante**: Considera que si tienes el método sobrecargado, el método que use varargs será la última opción que elegirá el compilador para comprobar tu código, al igual que será la última opción que la JVM usará en caso que invoques a uno de los métodos sobrecargados.

Ejemplo:

```
public void metodoX(int x) {
    System.out.println("MetodoX con un argumento");
}

public void metodoX(int x, int y) {
    System.out.println("MetodoX con dos argumentos");
}

public void metodoX(int ... args) {
    System.out.println("MetodoX con varargs");
}

//...

metodoX(10);
metodoX(10, 20);
metodoX(10, 20, 30);
```

Salida:

```
MetodoX con un argumento
MetodoX con dos argumentos
MetodoX con varargs
```

Answer (score 5):

Significa que es una variable de argumentos es similar a un arreglo ( [] ) y soporta que le envies 0 o mas parametros separador por una coma (,)

Ejemplo :

```
//version de metodo main con arreglo comun
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    metodo(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); // [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 ]
    metodo(); //sin argumentos
}

//version de metodo main con una variable de argumentos
publc static void main (String ... args)
{
    metodo(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); // [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 ]
    metodo(); //sin argumentos
}


public static void metodo(int ... argumentos)
{
    if(argumentos.length > 0)
    {
        for(int pivote : argumentos)
        {
            System.out.println(pivote);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("sin argumentos");
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva

Saludos.